# My php variables are not being printed out.

Tags: php

```
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      echo '<a href="/community"><img id="visit-the-forums" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/visit-the-forums.png" alt="Check out the Forums!" /></a>'
    } else {
      echo '<a href="/community"><img id="join-the-forums" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/join-the-forums.png" alt="Join the Forums!" /></a>'
    }
    ?>
```

I think there is something wrong w/ the way I set up the "php bloginfo" code inside but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: try echoing `echo bloginfo(url)`

Comment: `bloginfo()` always prints the result itself, so @Glass' comment is incorrect > http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below should work for you. You had to make use of [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.string.php):

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  echo '<a href="/community"><img id="visit-the-forums" src="' . bloginfo('template_url'). '/images/visit-the-forums.png" alt="Check out the Forums!" /></a>'
} else {
  echo '<a href="/community"><img id="join-the-forums" src="' . bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/join-the-forums.png" alt="Join the Forums!" /></a>'
}
?>
```

Comment: oh yes php is not parsed within single quotes + 1

Comment: @Sarfraz not only that but the php tags we're being nested, which I don't believe is correct.

Comment: Strangely, this still doesn't seem to work. I've copied the entire code here: http://pastebin.com/xVDggv0G It's a WordPress site and this is the sidebar. The sidebar doesn't even show up.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 problems:

1. Most likely this code is not
   executing because you're `echo`ing a
   string that's delimited with single
   quotes and inside it you've put
   unescaped single quotes. (You can tell this is the case because even on this page, the syntax colouring is messed up :)
2. Even if you had escaped the single
   quotes (e.g. `<?php
   bloginfo(\'template_url\') ?>`) this
   would not work because you're using
   PHP to echo PHP code, which will then
   be passed to the browser, instead of
   being executed by the PHP engine.

What you need to do is to add the result of `bloginfo()` (or `get_bloginfo()`, see edit below) to the string you're outputting:

```
  echo '<a href="/community"><img id="visit-the-forums" src="'. bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/visit-the-forums.png" alt="Check out the Forums!" /></a>'
```

(note the correct usage of single-quotes as delimiters, and the correct syntax highlighting on this page: strings are reddish, code is black)

**EDIT**: if `bloginfo` here is the WordPress function, you will want to replace it in my code above with `get_bloginfo` which actually returns the result rather than printing it, but your original question wasn't clear about what `bloginfo` is/does.